# How to copy the data from an Elastic index of 150 GB size to another

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have an index "Index A" of size 150+ GB, there are few fields which needs to be converted to NESTED and for few fields the type to be changed from "keyword" to "text" and vice versa.

I have created a new index "Index B" with the necessary types/changes, as I could not modify the existing index to have NESTED type as it has data.

Whenever I use "POST _reindex" its getting into "Time Out error" both with and without filter query, what is the process to copy the 150+ GB of data from Index A to Index B ?

Answer (score 0):

Reindex is the way to go, however, as the process is going to last more than just a few seconds/minutes, you need to run the process in the background by adding `?wait_for_completion=false` to the URL:

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
    ...
}
```

The call is going to return immediately with a task id that you can use to monitor the progress of your reindex, using the following command:

```
GET _tasks/<task_id>
```

When the task has completed, you can delete it using

```
DELETE .tasks/<task_id>
```